# Getting UnsatisfiedLinkError with Daniel Shiffman's Processing library for Kinect

Tags: processing, kinect

I'm trying to get some of the examples in Daniel Shiffman's updated Kinect library to work. I installed openkinect, and have all the libraries in the right place. I'm not really sure what the problem is, but the glview test in the terminal works fine with the Kinect plugged in. I'm running 10.5.8 on an intel Macbook (2007) and am using Processing 1.21. I realized that nearly everyone running the libraries are using Snow Leopard, could that be the problem? Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I found this page which was very helpful, but alas I am still getting errors.

http://openkinect.org/wiki/Installation/Compilation_Guides

Oddly the openframeworks demo works perfectly, so I don't think the installation of openkinect was the problem. I asked the same question on the google groups page for openkinect. I'm not the only one with this problem, I saw it popping up on the Processing forums as well. Don't hesitate to ask if there's anything I can clarify.

Here are the errors:

```
processing.app.debug.RunnerException: UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/milespeyton/Desktop/projects/processing/libraries/openkinect/library/libKinect.jnilib: 
    at processing.app.Sketch.placeException(Sketch.java:1543)
    at processing.app.debug.Runner.findException(Runner.java:583)
    at processing.app.debug.Runner.reportException(Runner.java:558)
    at processing.app.debug.Runner.exception(Runner.java:498)
    at processing.app.debug.EventThread.exceptionEvent(EventThread.java:367)
    at processing.app.debug.EventThread.handleEvent(EventThread.java:255)
    at processing.app.debug.EventThread.run(EventThread.java:89)
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/milespeyton/Desktop/projects/processing/libraries/openkinect/library/libKinect.jnilib: 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1822)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1739)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:822)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:993)
    at org.openkinect.Context.<clinit>(Context.java:43)
    at org.openkinect.processing.Kinect.start(Kinect.java:40)
    at RGBDepthTest.setup(RGBDepthTest.java:33)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:1583)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:1503)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:613)
```

Comment: You may get results if you ask on the OpenKinect mailing list.

Comment: @ConnorAlbright Still having this issue. Anybody encounter another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone with the same problem, I solved it by upgrading to Snow Leopard. I'm not exactly sure why this worked, but all of the Kinect Processing libraries work fine for me now.